# Magento - Insert the media gallery of the product in view.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, php, product-images, gallery, view

I'm trying to move the media gallery of the product from the `media.phtml` file to the `view.phtml` file. Basically I want to move the div with `class = "more-views"` which is contained in the `media.phtml` file.

When I try to insert it in a section of the `view.phtml` file and try to click on the product thumbnail, the effect of the **photo change does not work**. I noticed that this effect works only if the media gallery's thumbnails are inserted into the div with `class = "gallery gallery_img"` which is in the `media.phtml` file.

So, how can I make the effect of the image change of the product work if I move the thumbnails of the photos in the `view.phtml` file?

Thanks so much

I attached a photo for a better comprehension:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your div must be like below in right section as per your your need:

```
<div class="more-views">
    <h2>More Views</h2>
    <ul class="product-image-thumbs">
                    <li>
            <a class="thumb-link" href="#" title="" data-image-index="0">
                <img src="http://demo.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/75x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/w/b/wbk009t.jpg" alt="" height="75" width="75">
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li>
            <a class="thumb-link" href="#" title="" data-image-index="1">
                <img src="http://demo.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/75x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/w/b/wbk009a_2.jpg" alt="" height="75" width="75">
            </a>
        </li>
                    <li>
            <a class="thumb-link" href="#" title="" data-image-index="2">
                <img src="http://demo.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/75x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/w/b/wbk009c_2.jpg" alt="" height="75" width="75">
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

i tried it with above structure and its working

can you run below script in console and test:

```
jQuery('.product-image-thumbs .thumb-link').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var jlink = $j(this);
            var target = $j('#image-' + jlink.data('image-index'));

            ProductMediaManager.swapImage(target);
        });
```

Comment: I tried but not work. When i copy this code in view.phtml and i try to click on thumbnail the main image not change...

Comment: Your structure of Element is same as mine?

Comment: Yes is the same. Currently only div "more-views" located in the media.phtml works

Comment: @Gabriel91 , check updated answer

Comment: Hi man, thanks i resolved this! I duplicated the jQuery function in media.phtml and i created a new div of "more-views" in view.phtml. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Gabriel91 , happy to hear that you solved issue. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76312/discussion-between-chirag-rajput-and-gabriel91).